# Orbited launch problems: " ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'formatters' "

Tags: python, django, comet, stomp, orbited

I'm trying to get Orbited started, but unfortunately I'm running into more than a few problems!  First, problems with easy_install (solved).  Then, proceeded on with instructions from http://mischneider.net/?p=125.  But when using `orbited -c orbited.cnf` I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\orbited-script.py", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('orbited==0.7.11beta3', 'console_scripts', 'orbited')()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\orbited-0.7.11beta3-py2.7.egg\orbited\star
t.py", line 133, in main
    logging.config.fileConfig(options.config)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\config.py", line 70, in fileConfig
    formatters = _create_formatters(cp)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\config.py", line 106, in _create_formatters
    flist = cp.get("formatters", "keys")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ConfigParser.py", line 567, in get
    raise NoSectionError(section)
ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'formatters'
```

And here's my config file (orbited.cnf):

```
[listen]
http://:9000
stomp://:61613

[access]
* -> localhost:61613

[global]
session.ping_interval = 300
```

(Edit: I may need a [format] section?)
I have absolutely nothing, and most of the resources I find point to orbited.org, which has been down since like, the day since I got interested in orbited.  Help me please!  I really want to start working on cool live django apps!

Comment: You're probably missing a `[formatters]` section in your configuration file. Sadly, I can't recall what should be in that section. :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a sample config file in the tar file.
You can find it online at https://bitbucket.org/desmaj/orbited/src/1a8a47861f1d/daemon/orbited.cfg.example

just copy everything from the [loggers] section onwards.
set relevant level=DEBUG wherever you want more debug information

-- sid

Comment: This. The relevant part in the config is indeed the one that says `[formatters]`.

Comment: It seems to be working now.  One question though: the tutorial suggests that something to the effect of                              `02/18/10 18:12:31:117 INFO   orbited.start  proxy protocol active
02/18/10 18:12:31:118 INFO   orbited.start  Listening http@9000
02/18/10 18:12:31:119 INFO   orbited.start  Listening stomp@61613` should be output, but I see no messages.  Is there a setting I need to change so it shows some kind of message to verify that it's working correctly? @sid

Comment: You'll probably have to change the logger level to INFO instead of WARN.

Comment: I haven't tried level = DEBUG but with level = INFO it seems to be working business as usual now!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone wants to just C&P the code I added as per sid's suggestion.  If it's useful please upvote his answer, not this one!

```
# new logging configuration using the python stdlib logging.fileConfig
[loggers]
keys = root,orbited,orbited_TCPConnectionResource

[handlers]
keys = console,errors,connections

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = NOTSET
handlers = console

[logger_orbited]
level = WARN
handlers = errors
qualname = orbited

[logger_orbited_TCPConnectionResource]
level = DEBUG
handlers = connections
qualname = orbited.cometsession.TCPConnectionResource

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = INFO
formatter = generic

[handler_errors]
class = FileHandler
args = ('error.log', 'w')
level = WARN
formatter = generic

[handler_connections]
class = FileHandler
level = DEBUG
formatter = generic
args = ('connections.log', 'w')

[formatter_generic]
format = %(asctime)s,%(msecs)03d %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s] %(message)s
```